# Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to this angular world, i am bit confused with the use of double curly braces    {{}}
and single curly braces{} or sometime no curly brace is used to include the expression like in the directives

1. `ng-class={expression}`
2. `normal data binding like{{obj.key}}`
3. `ng-hide='mydata==="red"'`

Answer (score 290, accepted):

### {{}} - double curly braces:

`{{}}` are Angular expressions and come quite handy when you wish to write stuff to HTML:

```
<div>
    {{planet.name == "Earth" ? "Yeah! We 're home!" : "Eh! Where 're we?"}}
</div>

<!-- with some directives like `ngSrc` -->
<img ng-src="http://www.example.com/gallery/{{hash}}"/>

<!-- set the title attribute -->
<div ng-attr-title="{{celebrity.name}}">...

<!-- set a custom attribute for your custom directive -->
<div custom-directive custom-attr="{{pizza.size}}"></div>
```

Don't use these at a place that is already an expression!

For instance, the directive `ngClick` treats anything written in between the quotes as an expression:

```
<!-- so dont do this! -->
<!-- <button ng-click="activate({{item}})">... -->
```

### {} - single curly braces:

`{}` as we know stand for objects in JavaScript. Here, too, nothing different:

```
<div ng-init="distanceWalked = {mon:2, tue:2.5, wed:0.8, thu:3, fri:1.5, 
sat:2, sun:3}">
```

With some directives like `ngClass` or `ngStyle` that accept map:

```
<span ng-style="{'color' : 'red'}">{{viruses.length}} viruses found!</span>

<div ng-class="{'green' : vegetable == 'lettuce', 
'red' : vegetable == 'tomato'}">..
```

### no curly braces:

As already mentioned just go braceless when inside expressions. Quite simple:

```
<div ng-if="zoo.enclosure.inmatesCount == 0">
    Alarm! All the monkeys have escaped!
</div>
```

Comment: We can use {{}} with ng-include directive, in ng-src property.

Comment: Like someone mentioned in the comments, Double braces {{}} is supposed to be put in ng-src directive between quotes.  But why is ng-src able to do that?  Is there a name for special kind of directives that takes {{}} inside quotes?

Comment: Is there any difference between {{foo-bar}} and "{{foo-bar}}" ?

Comment: I had to do a bit more research on this myself to fully understand it, but I thought this blog post really helped along with @CodeHater's answer, [Why does AngularJS sometimes use single braces { }, sometimes double braces {{ }}, and sometimes no braces?](http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/02/why-does-angularjs-sometimes-use-single-braces-sometimes-double-braces-and-sometimes-no-braces.html)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post and might be a bit off topic, but this is in response to @DonD and @GafrieldKlon...

It would seem a watcher is actually placed if you were to use the `ng-bind` directive, **not** when using `{{}}`. That being said, I believe @riyas answer above is still partially true in that **avoiding** `{{}}` is generally **better** for performance, but not for the reason stated.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/8990667) to another post explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing about `{{}}`
it is also used as Watcher..
please avoid as much as possible for better performance

Comment: Did you mean {{}} degrades performance? Can you please provide a source to prove that?

Comment: Can someone confirm that?