# AngularJS insert a value from the scope into ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS I have a link which I need to insert a value from the scope into, I have tried this:

```
  $scope.go = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        };

 <a ng-click="go('/edit/{{my.id}}')"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
```

but this just passes in `/edit/%7B%7Bmy.id%`

How is this possible in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this?

```
$scope.go = function (id) {
        $location.path('/edit/'+id);
};

 <a ng-click="go(my.id)"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
```

some useful information: [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

Comment: perfect this worked  ng-click="go('/edit/' + my.id)"