# Why does the directive ng-href need {{}} while other directives don't?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am just wondering why I need to add double curly braces for ng-href while some of the other directives don't need them?

```
<a ng-href="{{myScopeVar}}" ng-if="myScopeVar">link</a>
```

Notice that `ng-href` needs braces while `ng-if` doesn't.

Comment: Just suppose you want to build the url dynamically, e.g.: `ng-href="#/foobar/{{barfoo}}"`. Also you might want to read the description in the [manual](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref) for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I am not quite sure about your question. But i think your are wondering why there are different syntax styles in angular directives. First off all, please have a look at this post: [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js) The answer explains the difference between `{{}}`, `{}` and no braces.

For your concrete examples, as in the documentation stated: `ng-href` requires a template   (any string which can contain `{{}}` markup), while ng-if requires an expression - e.g. you may not write `{{}}`, because angular evaluates it.

If you have a look at the angular sources you will see, that `ng-href` uses `attr.$observe` while ng-if uses the `$scope.$watch` function. $observe is caled on every change of the attribute value. $watch is called, when the expression results to a new value.

But why these two different ways? I think one point is easier usage and code readability. Right now you can write:

```
<a ng-href="http://yourdomain.com/users/{{userId}}/post/{{postId}}">title</a>
```

As you can see, you only write an expression for dynamically inserted `userId` and `postId` values. If `ng-href` would also use the `$watch` function we had to write (*don't do this because it wil not work - it only demonstrates the difference*):

```
<a ng-href="'http://yourdomain.com/users/'+userId+'/post'+postId">title</a>
```

Comment: Can I use a function output for `ng-href` like `ng-href="{{my_function()}}"`?

Comment: @ShellFish yes you can

Answer (score -1):

Even if Iuse `ng-href` `data-ng-href` it throws error for validation.
I used `<link rel="stylesheet" data-ng-href="{{datas}}" href="/">` in order to pass validating error.

Hope it will helps someone