# AngularJs ng-href dynamic link with scope not updating/working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I am having a problem where an  tag with an ng-href tag link with a scope parameter inside of it does update when the scope changes. I read in this answer ([Why does the directive ng-href need {{}} while other directives don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303706/why-does-the-directive-ng-href-need-while-other-directives-dont)) that ng-href uses $observe which should change ng-href when the scope value is changed.

Here is the html links in question. It is has two buttons to change the year, a p tag to show the year (id=yearp), and a button for each month (with the links that are not working properly)

```
<button id="left" style="display:inline;">left </button>
<p id="yearp" style="display:inline;"> {{curyear}} </p>
<button id="right" style="display:inline;"> right </button><br/>

<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-01-01"><button style="display:inline;"> January </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-02-01"><button style="display:inline;"> February </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-03-01"><button style="display:inline;"> March </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-04-01"><button style="display:inline;"> April </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-05-01"><button style="display:inline;"> May </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-06-01"><button style="display:inline;"> June </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-07-01"><button style="display:inline;"> July </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-08-01"><button style="display:inline;"> August </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-09-01"><button style="display:inline;"> September </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-10-01"><button style="display:inline;"> October </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-11-01"><button style="display:inline;"> November </button></a>
<a ng-href="#calendar/month/{{curyear}}-12-01"><button style="display:inline;"> December </button></a>
```

And the angular controller for this page looks like this

```
App.controller('yearController', function($scope){
    var cdt = new Date();
    $scope.curyear = cdt.getFullYear();
    $("#left").click(function(){
        $scope.curyear = $scope.curyear - 1;
        $("#yearp").text($scope.curyear);
    });
    $("#right").click(function(){
        $scope.curyear = $scope.curyear + 1;
        $("#yearp").text($scope.curyear);
    });
});
```

Now pressing the buttons prev and next correctly change the $scope.curyear and is updated in the yearp tag, but pressing any of the links will still take me to (if pressing January) "calendar/month/2015-01-01" regardless of what $scope.curyear is. Anyone have any input on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not updating is because your click callback is outside of the Angular [`$digest` loop](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/). But, [you shouldn't be accessing the DOM in a controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for quite a few reasons which are detailed in Angular docs and in a number of StackOverflow tickets.

**Recommended Reading:**

- ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)
- [Separating DOM manipulation from Angular controllers - Best Practice wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988547/separating-dom-manipulation-from-angular-controllers-best-practice-wanted)
- [Things I Wish I Were Told About Angular.js](http://ruoyusun.com/2013/05/25/things-i-wish-i-were-told-about-angular-js.html)

Update your HTML to:

```
<button id="left" ng-click="prevYear()" style="display:inline;">left </button>
<p id="yearp" style="display:inline;"> {{curyear}} </p>
<button id="right" ng-click="nextYear()" style="display:inline;"> right </button><br/>
```

And your controller:

```
App.controller('yearController', function($scope){
    var cdt = new Date();
    $scope.curyear = cdt.getFullYear();
    $scope.prevYear = function(){
        --$scope.curyear;
    }
    $scope.nextYear = function(){
        ++$scope.curyear;
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the incredibly quick and detailed answer! I am pretty new to AngularJS so I was not aware that it is bad to access the DOM in a controller. I was also not aware that you can store functions in the scope. The changes fixed my problem. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

David Boskovic is correct.

I just want to add some basic points regarding angularJS.

In your code you are mixing up angular with jquery event. You are not supposed to do that. You can use `ng-click` attribute to fire a event on click of any element.

I think you already seen that how to use `ng-click` in the David Boskovic's answer. So, I am not explaining how to use `ng-click`.

And also, I want to point one more issue in your approach.

`$("#yearp").text($scope.curyear);` is a way of jquery not angular JS.

If you bind this variable to your html, then any change occurred to this variable will automatically updated on html also. So, no need to use `$("#yearp").text($scope.curyear);`

Note, to increment a variable, here `curyear` you can simply write your logic in html itself.

```
<button id="left" ng-click="curyear = curyear + 1" style="display:inline;">left </button>
```

So, you can do things easier using angular JS !!!