# change url location on click the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change location on clicking the div .

Below is code

```
    <div class="divsub" ng-repeat="item1 in content" ng-click="go('/{{item1.title }}')">
    <div class="divsubtitle"><a >{{item1.title}}</a></div>
    <div class="divsubinner"></div>
    <div class="divsublink">
         <div style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:19px">View Demo</div>
         <div style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:10px">Download</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my controller

```
first2.controller('nameListCtrl', function ($scope,urls_list) 
{
    $scope.content=urls_list;
    $scope.go=function(path)
    {
        alert(path)
    }
});
```

Why alert is not working on clicking the div

Comment: alert(path) to alert(path); Unless it was a typo.

Comment: @Grimbode if this is Javascript, the semicolon is optional.

Comment: i tried that too still not working

Comment: it works when i pass something like this ng-click="go('aaaaaa')"

Comment: @user3792784 plz check my answer.Does it work for u??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SImply change

```
ng-click="go('item1.title)"
```

to

```
ng-click="go(item1.title)"
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/27RhE/1/)

Comment: i tried that too still not working... 
 
it works when i pass something like this ng-click="go('aaaaaa')" instead of ng-click="go('/{{item1.title }}')"

Answer (score 2):

No need to use interpolation `{{ }}` because its already an angular expression inside an angular directive `ng-click`

Just use

```
ng-click="go(item1.title)"
```

Also see when to use single, double and no curly braces in angular directives:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17879046/1177295

Answer (score 0):

So your HTML can be changed as like below

```
<div class="divsub" ng-repeat="item1 in content" ng-click="ng-click="go(item1.title)"">
<div class="divsubtitle"><a >{{item1.title}}</a></div>
<div class="divsubinner"></div>
<div class="divsublink">
     <div style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:19px">View Demo</div>
     <div style="float:left;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:10px">Download</div>
</div>
```

From the above comments and answer