# how to load angular $scope data into a location.href?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following

```
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="data in datas" title='{{ data.name }}' onClick="location.href='\{{ data.name }}'" >{{ data.name }}</div><br/>
    </div>
```

in my angular file i have

```
 var mainApp= angular.module('mainApp',[]);

 mainApp.controller('formCTR',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
   $http.post('/here',{ data: 'something' }).success(
       function(data){
          $scope.datas=data;
       }
   )
  }]);
```

when i do the click the url shows

```
http://localhost:3000/url/{{ data.name }}
```

how do i display the name of the data inside the onClick to

```
http://localhost:3000/url/right_name
```

thanks

Comment: have you tried using ng-click. [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201753/angular-js-how-when-to-use-ng-click-to-call-a-route), [or this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696238/change-url-location-on-click-the-div)

Comment: thanks for your help @guest but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: @luis what is the scope of data  it is  var or $scope variable and if it is scope variable then your $http configuration and html page scope is same or different ? please provide fiddle or code with controller and html so we understand the scope of your prgram

Comment: use https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-click` instead of `onClick`...

Controller

```
...
$scope.redirect = function(route) {
   $location.path('/' + route);
}
...
```

Template

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas" title='{{ data.name }}' ng-click="redirect({{ data.name }})" >{{ data.name }}</div><br/>
</div>
```

...or use an anchor tag and `ng-href`.

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas" title="{{ data.name }}"><a ng-href="\{{ data.name }}">{{ data.name }}</a></div><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-click` doesn't know what `location` is...it's not within controller scope... it is a window global

Comment: thank @hally9k , the second one worked!, wished the first would worked too so i won't have to write another css for the a tag.

Comment: No the first one won't work unless and until you expose `$location` service on your `$scope` object. You can only access properties added(exposed) on the $scope object. In general it is not a good practice. See my answer below for details

Comment: @hally9k After looking at your code, you don't need the single quotes within `ng-href` after the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do redirection in angular, you can use either of the 2 steps using 'ng-click' using a click handler or 'ng-href' with a url as below:

```
<div>
<div ng-repeat="data in datas" title='{{ data.name }}' ng-click="redirect(data.name)" >{{ data.name }}</div><br/>
</div>
```

and in your controller scope add the `redirect` function

```
$scope.redirect = function (route) {
  $location.path('/' + route);
}
```

This approach allows you to use the same function for redirection to multiple routes by changing the parameter.

The second method is an easy and elegant approach, if you just need redirection using the `ng-href` directive:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="data in datas" title='{{ data.name }}'>
    <a ng-href="/{{ data.name }}">{{ data.name }}</a>
  </div><br/>
</div>
```