# AngularJS ng-repeat with multiple radio inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got small problem with ng-repeat on persons with multiple radio inputs (yes/no). Input names should be different because of name="person.name" but it behaves like they all are the same. Somebody knows how to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Chotkos/EbU8g/

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Decisions</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people">
            <label>{{person.name}}
                <input type="radio" ng-model="person.decision" name="person.name" value="Yes" />
                <input type="radio" ng-model="person.decision" name="person.name" value="No" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: "John"
    }, {
        name: "Paul"
    }, {
        name: "George"
    }, {
        name: "Ringo"
    }];
}
```

Comment: For more information about when to use curly braces in angular, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `{{ person.name }}`, rather than `"person.name"` in that context.

Comment: and, you can use the $index variable, as name="person{{$index}}", to avoid repeated values in person.name

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you got downvoted. Your question was fine. So you are using the `name` property which is traditional in an HTML form. Since `name` isn't part of angular, you need to wrap the `person.name` in curly brackets `name="{{person.name}}"` so angular knows to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chotkos/EbU8g/
that happend because you wrapped all inputs into label tag

```
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <p>Decisions</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in people">
                <label>{{person.name}}</label>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="person.decision" name="person.name" value="Yes" />
                <input type="radio" ng-model="person.decision" name="person.name" value="No" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```