# Don't understand the syntactical inconsistencies in Angular

Tags: angularjs

A few examples:

```
<img ng-src="{{some.thing}}">
<button ng-class="{active: data.checkThing()}">
<div ng-repeat="thing in things"></div>
```

As someone learning Angular, this is highly confusing. I never know whether I need `{ }` or `{{ }}` or neither. Can someone explain what these mean and when to use which?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**{{}}:**

You use `{{}}` when you want to evaluate an expression, such as:

1. `$scope` variables, e.g:

   `$scope.myVar = "test";`

   And in HTML:

   `<div>{{myVar}}</div>` will result in `<div>test</div>`
2. Basic calculations, such as: `{{ 1 + 1 }}`, `{{ myVar + " add on" }}`
3. Result of a function on the controller so it can be displayed
4. Etc..

**{}:**

Condition, used directives such as `ng-class/ng-style`. It means the left-hand side will be in effect if the expression on the right-hand side evaluates to true. The following expression means that the button will have the class "active", if `data.checkThing()` evaluates to true:

```
<button ng-class="{active: data.checkThing()}">
```

**Neither:**

When you want to address objects, like you do in the `ng-repeat`, you have to iterate on objects, like you do in C#/Javascript/etc..

So because you're working with the objects themselves, you don't need to evaluate anything, and simply address them as they are variables on your scope:

`<div ng-repeat="item in items">...</div>`

If you are using directives for instance, and you have an isolated scope and want to bind a variable in that scope to an instance, you will use no brackets:

```
<div myDirective item="myItem"></div>
```

And in the directive you can have a reference to that item by doing:

```
angular.module('app').directive('my-directive', function () {
    return {
       scope: {
          item: "=" //references the object that exists in 
                    //attribute `item` on the DOM element the directive is on
       }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Single braces** are used for directives accepting an object parameter, which may be more than one value. It is analogous to a JSON object.

For example:

```
ng-class="{active: true, highlight:true}"
```

**Double braces** are used to represent an AngularJS expression.

For example

```
<div>{{ item.name }}<div> (evaluates to string)

<div>{{ item.name == "Sam" }}<div> (evaluates to boolean)
```

**No braces** are used for directives accepting a single value argument.

For example, data binding:

```
ng-model="people.jim"
```

Answer (score 0):

{active:data.checkThing()} signifies object creation-----you are constructing and actually passing an object to ng-class directive in the angularjs library.

{{some.thing}} signifies 2-way data binding with the actual ng-model that reflects the changes in model data as and when it occurs.

Hope it helps.If this answers your queries kindly accept this as answer or comment back if not.