# AngularJS ng-click work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show some details about a list of procedures using an AngularJS function. Every procedure is identified by a unique ID so I use it as a parameter in the function.

If I use this line of code it works

```
<a ng-click="showDetails(1)">Show Details</a>
```

While using this one it doesn't work

```
<a ng-click="showDetails({{1}})">Show Details</a>
```

Shouldn't everything inside double braces be solved?

---

EDIT: seems obvious but, given the comments, it isn't...

This is an example to understand why argument isn't fine this way, in my production version I need to perform much advanced calculations that writing 1...

Comment: No need for interpolation on directives.

Comment: is 1 a variable you set in your controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling a directive, such as `ng-click`, you are already evaluating any JS you throw inside it because they accept an expression.

So, if you try calling `ng-click="showDetails({{1}})"` it's the same as calling a function with a JS object `{}` wrapping another object `{1}`. Where 1 is just an usual string/number

You could take a further read into this one: [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

**[EDIT]** I guess this link could help you even more than the previous one: [How to get evaluated attributes inside a custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371159/how-to-get-evaluated-attributes-inside-a-custom-directive)

Comment: you're welcome! i´ve edited the answer to add another link that seems to fit your question better