# Angular ng-show not working as intended in simple example script

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
    <!--<other HTML elements>  -->
    <div ng-controller="nameController">
    <div ng-show="{{name}}">
        My Name
    </div>
    <span ng-click="showName()">Show Name</span>
    </div>
    <!--<other HTML elements>  -->
```

And my angular controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('nameController', function($scope){
    $scope.name = false;
    $scope.showName = function()
    {
        $scope.name = true;
    }   
});
```

When I run this, "My Name" is hidden initially as expected, but clicking on Show does not display it. If I do `console.log($scope.name)` then it displays `true`

I have been stuck with this for hours now...what am I doing wrong? Any help is very much appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the curly braces from `{{name}}`.

```
<div ng-show="name">
```

Adding this to give the answer more relevance: [AngularJS Curly Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

Comment: Oh wow, that works!! I think {{}} is needed for expressions...If I have to do `ng-show={{val1 || val2}}` is that correct way? or should that also be without curly braces?

Comment: I'm new to angular, so I'm not sure about exceptions to this, but typically when in an angular attribute, braces are not needed.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable you just need to keep in mind that AngularJS expressions, i.e. `ng-something` do not need curly braces

Comment: @SterlingArcher anytime