# Why do we use double braces for ng-src in AugularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm confused about AngularJS expressions.

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_expressions.asp), I learned that

1. AngularJS expressions can be written inside double braces: `{{ expression }}`.
2. AngularJS expressions can also be written inside a directive: `ng-bind="expression".`

But why do we use `ng-src={{...}}` instead of `ng-src="..."`?

Is the `ng-src` a special case when dealing with AngularJS expressions?

Comment: Refer to the official documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: Have you checked my answer ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is a special case for `ng-src`, as it is waiting for a `template` parameter, which is a `string` with any kind of interpolation inside (`{{}}`), as stated in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />
```

This depends on **how** the directive is specified by itself.

Comment: It does make sense as you said!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both.
When you are binding certain dynamic values at that time use like this.

```
ng-src="{{myVar}}"
```

When you are binding static values at that time use like this.

```
<img ng-src="string"></img>
```

Hope this will make you clear.

Comment: For the directives other than ng-src, for example ng-repeat, ng-model, why don't we use double braces for dynamic values as you said?

Answer (score 0):

This has *sort of* been asked already, referring to this question might be helpful

[Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

Comment: I read this before, but still can not understand why we use double braces with ng-src. Is this the only directive that we should use double braces with?