# Change ng-hide value when clicking button

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a small example to change the value of `ng-hide` after clicking button, but it didn't work.

I've tried:

```js
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hide= false
  $scope.change = function () {
    $scope.hide = !$scope.hide  
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
  <p ng-hide="{{hide}}">some text...</p>
  <button ng-click="change()">change</button>
</div>
```

And my question: what am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: `ng-hide="hide"`

Comment: are you including js and html code in one file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets around hide in your template.. that will help.

```
ng-hide="hide"
```

Comment: like this `<p ng-hide="hide">some text...</p>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) condition like

```
$scope.hide = ($scope.hide) ? false : true;
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's longer than my current statement

Comment: What would be the benefit of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses `{{...}}` to mark something as an expression.
However `hide` is already an angular expression so you get expression of expression which breaks the two way binding and is only evaluated once on pageloading...

So to fix your problem simply remove the brackets

```
ng-hide="hide"
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js) for more information.

```js
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.hide= false
  $scope.change = function () {
    $scope.hide = !$scope.hide
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
  <p ng-hide="hide">some text...</p>
  <button ng-click="change()">change</button>
</div>
```