# AngularJS - When should we avoid using {{}}?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Interpurting `angular.js`

I saw a tutorial about AngularJS, showing 3 examples:

```
<div class="gallery" ng-show="product.images.length"> 

<img class="img img-circle img-thumbnail center-block" ng-src="{{product.images[0]}}" />

<li ng-class="{ selected: true }">
```

when I tried to write a sample code I used the `{{}}` for all of the above:

```
<div class="gallery" ng-show={{product.images.length}}> 

<img class="img img-circle img-thumbnail center-block" ng-src="{{product.images[0]}}" />

<li ng-class="{{ selected: true }}">
```

Is it wrong?

when do I use `{{}}` then?

For example, it's a must for this condition?

```
<div class="gallery" ng-show={{product.images.length > 2}}>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js

Comment: And did it work when you use double curly brace?

Comment: already has a answer in this link which contains the   questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js

Comment: Oh @paone you're right :)

Comment: !!!!!!ok bro.... Alon Eitan.