# What is the diff between using {{...}} and without {{...}} and angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Actually I'm confused between when to use `{{ }}` when using angular directives and when to not to use `{{  }}`

For example:

```
<div data-ng-init="isHidden=false">
    <div data-ng-show="isHidden">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div data-ng-init="isHidden=false">
    <div data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm confused between these syntax ? What are the differences between those? And when to use what? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

It's all explained here: [Difference between double and single curly brace in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js)

For quick answer:

> {{}} are Angular expressions and come quite handy when you wish to
>   write stuff to HTML
>
> Don't use these at a place that is already an expression!
>
> For instance, the directive ngClick treats anything written in between
>   the quotes as an expression

Comment: so ng-show expect a expression ? and if used {{  }} inside expression it will automatically trim {{  }} ? without any error ? because i got not error in both ways

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference except the "look" u need to use the `{{value}}` syntax in case you want to write data anywhere in your html body

```
<div>{{value}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div data-ng-init="isHidden=false">
    <div data-ng-show="isHidden">
        ...
    </div>
</div>`
In This Situation data-ng-show = false , Takes From data-ng-init As Statically,if You Have Given true Then It Returns True .

But Here

```
<div data-ng-init="isHidden=false">
<div data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}">
    ...
</div>
```

{{}} Called As Expressions In Angular One Of The Most Important Concept
It Directly Evaluate If isHidden = true Or False Based On Any Condition Written In Your App.js File .
Example:

```
<div data-ng-init="isHidden=YourVariable">
<div data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}">
    ...
</div>
```

```
if(YourVariable == true){
   Do Somthing  
}
else{
 Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking when to use {{}} while assigning value to a attribute and when not.

It depends on the binding types of directive. '@' or '='

So here, you have to use:
`data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}"` if the binding type of directive scope data-ng-show is '@', that mean the data-ng-show will be expecting a string value. So in this case if you keep `data-ng-show="isHidden"` it will take data-ng-show's value as 'isHidden', but `data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}"` will take the value of the `$scope.isHidden` and assign to `data-ng-show`.

Now if the binding type of directive scope data-ng-show is '=', that means the data-ng-show will be expecting a value from a scope. So `data-ng-show="isHidden"` itself will take the value of he `$scope.isHidden` and assign to `data-ng-show`.

**Note:** all the default HTML attributes expect a string so you have to use {{}} for default HTML attributes.

Answer (score -1):

There is no as such major difference unless one uses them in the DOM for the `value`.

1. When one uses the following:

   `<div data-ng-show="isHidden">`

then, expression is evaluated and on the basis of it respective value, the `ng-show` either hides or displays the `div`. But the value of the `isHidden` cannot be seen, when one inspects the HTML using the browser developer tool.

2. When one uses the following:

   `<div data-ng-show="{{isHidden}}">`

In this case, the value of the `isHidden` can be seen from the developer tools, and the rest of the expression does evaluates the same as that of (1).