# Can't pass a parameter to my ui Modal with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

In my angularJS app, I'm trying to pass a parameter to a modal popup so that when the Modal link is click, a name is displayed in the popup.  The modal link is coming from a custom directive which is getting the list on names from an external service.

I've tried following [this tutorial to Create an Angularjs Popup Using Bootstrap UI](https://www.formget.com/angularjs-popup/) along with the [documentation for $uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) as that tutorial is a bit outdated.

I can get the modal PopUp and controller working but I can't pass a parameter to it.

I replicated the issue on [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHDtc7AZRvWzYjztQuCp?p=preview).

This problem is I can't get the `titlename` param passed to the `popupController` from the `listings` directive (see [script.js in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHDtc7AZRvWzYjztQuCp?p=preview)).  I don't think I have the resolve set up correctly.  With the debugger set in Chrome I can see the `titlename` value up to this point.

```
app.directive('listings', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        ...
        controller: ['$scope','$uibModal', function listingsDirectiveController($scope,$uibModal) {
            $scope.open = function (titlename) {
                var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'popup.html',
                    controller: 'popupController',
                    titlename: titlename,
                    resolve: {
                        item: function(){
                            return titlename;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }]
    };
}]);
```

But it doesn't get passed to the `popupController`.  In the below code the `titlename` has value `undefined`

```
app.controller('popupController', ['$scope','$uibModalInstance', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance, titlename) {
    $scope.title1 = titlename;
    $scope.close = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?  Is this the correct way to use `resolve` in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a double brace when using `ng-click`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js) post for more information on using the double curly braces. So your listings directive should be something like this. You were passing the actual string `'{{item.name}}'`

```
<a href="#" ng-click="open(item.name)">{{item.name}} -Popup</a>
```

Then in your `popupController`, you were not passing the resolved `item` value. The controller should read:

```
app.controller('popupController', ['$scope','$uibModalInstance', 'item', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance, titlename) {
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOXzvzYjM5m2dFgV02Yk?p=preview)

Comment: thank you, that was it exactly.  I had tried passing the item value before and a bunch of other ways but with `'{{item.name}}'` it kept not working, thanks a mil

Comment: I tried adding the popup to index.html rather than from within the directive with `<a ng-click="pgCtrl.open(pgCtrl.obj[1].name)">in page popup</a>` using the same method, and with the logic within the pgCtrl but it didn't work.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Holy do you have a plunker?

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to pass `item.name`, not the literal string `'{{item.name}}'` to your `open` method so change your template to

```
ng-click="open(item.name)"
```

---

Second, your resolved property is named `item` but you seem to be expecting `titlename` so change it to

```
resolve: {
    titlename: function() {
        return titlename;
    }
}
```

---

And finally, you don't have an injection annotation for `titlename` in your controller so you need to add it

```
app.controller('popupController', ['$scope','$uibModalInstance', 'titlename',
function ($scope,$uibModalInstance, titlename) {
    // ...
}])
```

---

Fixed Plunker ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/ee7Psz2jXbVSkD0mfhS9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

First, in your `listingsDirective.html`, don't use curly brackets to pass in variables. Also, by adding `titlename1` to the directive `$scope` and sharing that parent scope with the child modal, you can access the variables in your modal.

```
app.directive('listings', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data:'=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'listingsDirective.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope','$uibModal', function listingsDirectiveController($scope,$uibModal) {
            $scope.open = function (titlename) {
              $scope.titlename = titlename;
                var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'popup.html',
                    controller: 'popupController',
                    scope: $scope,
          resolve: {
            item: function(){
              return $scope.titlename;
            }
          }
                });
            }
        }]
    };
}]);

app.controller('popupController', ['$scope','$uibModalInstance', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.title1 = $scope.titlename;
    $scope.close = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

New Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RrzhGCLuBYniGGWvRYI9?p=preview