# Display function result with dynamically param

Tags: html, angularjs

I would like to display in my html the result from a function declared in my controller.
So, for example:

```
{{ vm.getValue({{data}}) }}
```

The data value is from a ng-repeat.

Do you have some ideas? thanks.

Comment: just `{{vm.getValue(data)}}` will do. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js) post on curly brace usage

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like a charm