# Why 'ng-value' is not working where as 'value' is working while evaluating Angular Expressions. i.e markup {{expression}}?

Tags: angularjs

```
Enter the Dollar Amount  <br>
1--<input type="text" ng-model="dollar1"  ></input> <br>
2--<input type="text" ng-model="dollar2" ></input> <br>
3--Not Working-<input type="text"  ng-value="{{dollar1 * dollar2}}" ></input>    <br>
4--Working<input type="text"  value="{{dollar1 * dollar2}}" ></input>  <br>
5--Working<input type="text"  ng-value="dollar1 * dollar2" ></input> <br>
```

Although the 5th one works if we use ng-value without curly braces

Comment: It is as you said, most of the directives (ng-..) don't use the curly braces
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js/17879046#17879046

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Angular-Directive **ng-value**, the expression passed in is treated as an Angular code which can directly interpret dollar1 and dollar2 as scope-variables.
AngularJS will process the directive **ng-value** and will add/set the result in the **value** attribute of the correspondig **input** element.

Using the html-built-in attribute **value**, you will need to use the curly braces to inject Angular code.
In this case AngularJS will just replace the expression **{{dollar1 * dollar2}}** to its result.

Your Not Working example is not working because the AngularJS-directive is already expecting some real program code which must not start with curly braces. It should directly start with interpretable code.