# How do I use a scope variable in ng-repeat filter?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm entirely sure I'm going about this the wrong way but seeing how new I am with angularjs I can't figure out how to accomplish what I want. I have a set of users that I am loping through using `ng-repeat`, but I can't figure out how to filter by the scope variable `userId`. The `User id: <name>` is being printed out just fine, so there is no issues with the scope. How can I have the `ng-repeat` loop sort by this `userId`? If I'm going about it the wrong what, can you please link me documentation that will help me go about it the right way.

HTML:

```
User id: {{userId}}
<br>
User Name:
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{{userId}}">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
function PhoneDetailController($scope, $routeParams, Users){
     $scope.userId = $routeParams.userId;
}
```

Comment: May I ask where is `$scope.users` declared?

Comment: Sorry I left that out. It is coming in from an ngResource. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a `$scope` variable `userId` in ng-repeat like so

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userId">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically just no need of angular expressions `{{}}` since it is already inside an expression.

Couple of links to help you out if you need.

[Here is a blog explaining Two Thumb Rules](https://jaketrent.com/post/when-to-use-curlies-in-angular-directives/) when deciding whether or not to use curlies.

[When exactly to use double curly braces, single curly braces and no braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878560/difference-between-double-and-single-curly-brace-in-angular-js/17879046#17879046)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I didn't understand. Works perfectly.

Comment: To help you understand, updated the answer with couple of good links.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of `users` is like this:

```
[
    {id:1,name:'xxx'},
    {id:2,name:'yyy'}
]
```

You can use the 'orderBy' filter to sort it and use `filter` filter to filter it:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{id:userId} | orderBy: 'id' ">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

`id` is a property of `user` in `ng-repeat`.

And here are the documentations: [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) and [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)