# Why is interpolation syntax so unpredictable?

Tags: angularjs

For example:

```
<img ng-show="showMe" alt="image" class="img-preview" ng-src="{{imgSource}}"
    style="width: 100%; height: 180px;" />
```

in this case, why need I to wrap `imgSource` with braces and don't need the same with `showMe`?

And how should I recognize cases is it required or not? Is there any list of such requirements or strict rule of usage?

Comment: A trivial answer would be "because `ngShow` doesn't need a templated string but a boolean, and `ngSrc` needs a templated string". The alternative would be for `ngShow` to always require braces, which would again be an inconvenience - not on dev brain like now, but on dev fingers.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons would be that `ng-src` is a `string` type, in most of the use cases the domain of the URL won't change or it will be relative or it will be fixed,

So, if we think about what src can be then it can be  one of this three ones:

```
/

https://example.com

/images
```

Note: this things won't change for all the images, so what we need to provide is the image name.

and `ng-show` doesn't have much to hold on. it can be either `true` or `false`, so that can be easily compiled to `model`. where in case of `ng-src` angular needs to know that at what part it needs to compile the model into value. Recommend [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17879046/2630817)

Comment: @anatol `ng-model` is two way binding, you can not concatenate string and modelname, ng-model will be the variable only. I can not think about the scenario where you have to use the `string + model`. that will be handled on `$scope`. This is how they designed it.

Comment: thanks, good point. as I edited my question, I want to know rules what operates with this cases. could you provide me link to docs where it is declared?

Comment: @anatol as I provided recommend read in my answer, it is pretty much of what you should check.

Comment: @anatol at what point you want to understand cases? the predefined directives are quite clear what to you when according to angualrjs site documentation.