# Bootstrap caret class does not work with ng-bind

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-bind="user.displayName">
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

As you can see I use caret class from Bootstrap and ng-bind from AngularJS. Unfortunately when I use  mg-bind the caret is not visible on my webpage. However, when I don't use mg-bind and just inline the value like this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{user.displayName}}<b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

the caret is visible.

Any ideas how to make the caret visible while using ng-bind?

Comment: Have you tried another HTML element instead of `<b>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to **replace** the text content of the
>   specified HTML element with the value of a given expression

So, using `ng-bind` replaces the content of the element (including your caret).

You could do something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span ng-bind="user.displayName"></span><b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Edit: really good read semi-related to this topic: [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)