# values not getting updated when there is a style in the parent container angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am not sure what will be best approach to handle the situation .

```
my angular js code look like:
<span class="something" ng-hide="onsomecondition">
   {{value}}
</span>

.something{ text-align:left; padding:10px;}
```

Problem: in my dom val get updated but not able to display correct value in the screen .

but if i remove the class attribute it seems fine but than my styles are gone . Is there a way to make sure i can keep style and value updated correctly?

thank! in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem can be solve by using ng-bind . I am facing the same problem answered in this question :
[AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

```
<span ng-bind="value" ng-hide="onsomecondition">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ng-class in this case

```
<span ng-class="something" ng-hide="onsomecondition">
   {{value}}
</span>
```

Comment: it works over here http://jsfiddle.net/y8uyufag/1/ might be some other issue can you show your controller and check if thr is any console error

Comment: well seems like in your code also styles were not applied if you inspect. i just added background-color attribute and it does not seems like applying the style

http://jsfiddle.net/paulL/y8uyufag/2/

Comment: anyways find out the issue it should be ng-class="'something'" instead of ng-class="something" . need to pass a string. modify your code above an di will accept your answer ... thanks!