# Angular JS Nested ng-repeat for bootstrap badges

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to tag different video items in a bootstrap table. I'm already using an ng-repeat to loop over the array of objects which store video data. I'm now trying to create a nested ng-repeat to loop over another array of "tags" within the ng-repeat that creates each table row.

I'm getting some weird results though. I was hoping that I could just put an ng-repeat on the td and then put the angular expression in a span with the boostrap class "badge". Any thoughts as to whats going wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/jheimpel/6nh100ca/

```
       <tr ng-repeat="topic in topics">
          <td><a ng-href="#/{{topic.url}}"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
          <td>{{topic.topic}}</td>
          <td>{{topic.date}}</td>
          <td>{{topic.presenter}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="tag in topic.tags">
                <span class="badge">{{topic.tags}}</span>
          </td>
       </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
<span class="badge" ng-bind="tag"></span>
```

You're telling it to print out the array you're ng-repeating instead of the object the ng-repeat is giving you. Also ng-bind is better, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Comment: OK cool that works! I also changed the ng-repeat to the span tag as it was creating multiple table cells instead of the actual span.