# AngularJS : {{ }} codes show for a split second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend

How to avoid `{{ }}` codes from showing when the page is just starting up or loading AngularJS resources?

In my case, the `{{ c }}` is showing inside my dropdown which is really weird for my users.

I can't use `ng-bind` in my case because I am showing a variable from a `ng-repeat` inside the `option` html tags.

Here is the code,

```
<select ng-model="invoice.inCurrency">
    <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{ c }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Another Note: Use ng-options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `ng-cloak` at your controller definition (or wherever you don't want to see the template rendering... specs recommend placing it in small portions of the page):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-cloak>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to work with `ng-bind` instead of `{{}}` in your view. It is always possible, even in your code :

```
<select ng-model="invoice.inCurrency">
    <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies" ng-bind="c"></option>
</select>
```

Please refer to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular) to see the advantages of `ng-bind`