# How avoid to show {{ ... }} at the start?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bindings, interpolation-directive

I am developing some simple angularjs SPA and I have noticed that at the start, for less than a seconds, in the SPA are displayed many `{{ ... }}` before angularjs load the data.

How could I avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: use ng-cloak for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580159/differences-between-ng-bind-and-ng-cloak-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3):

> Basically the content show as `{{}}` are interpolation directive which
>   are nothing but angular un-compiled data.

You could use `ng-cloak` directive on your body that will have `display: none !important` CSS, you could use this directive as `class` or `attribute` with which you need to add the CSS rule given below.

**CSS**

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

### **Alternative**

Use `ng-bind` directive that will evaluate the expression inside the scope of the current controller.

Comment: @xRobot do you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

From the [website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

*The **ngCloak** directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.*

```
<body ng-app="yourAppName" ng-controller="yourController as b" class="ng-cloak">
```

And with the CSS styles

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  disply: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ngCloak is the thing you are looking for.

Docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 1):

don't data-bind inside of an element. use an attribute. the `ng-bind` attribute is what you're looking for.

So...

`<h1>{{ your.data }}</h1>`

will become

`<h1 ng-bind="your.data"></h1>`

`ng-cloak` works as well, but it's good to know about both.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-bind

It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ variable }}, This will avoid {{}} momentarily displayed by the browser. People use {{ variable }} because it is less verbose and more readable.

```
<div>
      <div ng-bind="name"></div>
</div>
```

Besides ng-bind you can also use ng-Cloak. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is the documentation