# Avoiding to show the html angular tags when loading AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm a newbie in Angular JS(I'm using #1.5.8)and I'm following the **docs.angularjs.org/tutorial** tutorials.

I've the html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>{{application_name | uppercase }}</h1>
        <p class="lead" >
   </div>
```

where is set in main.js

```
$scope.application_name='app';
```

everything is going well, but every time I reload manually(refresh localhost page) or with gulp, the page renders earlier the html,the user sees `application_name` printed in big and after is rendered with the wanted value.

My question is : 
**is there a way to avoid showing Angular js expressions when rendering the page for first time?**
I want that when I go to the localhost page, the page shows **app** and not
**application_name**

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: writing it like
'<h1 ng-cloak="application_name | uppercase"></h1>
 <p class="lead" >'
I still see the angular expression, ng-bind works instead

Comment: @FedericoNastasi please see my answer... in my opinion ng-bind is best but ngcloak works... you are not suppose to use it like  ng-cloak="application_name | uppercase".... you would use brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid it by not using brackets...

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 ng-bind="application_name | uppercase"></h1>
        <p class="lead" >
   </div>
```

As Stephen C commented above you can also use ngcloak..

```
<div class="jumbotron" ng-cloak>
        <h1>{{ application_name | uppercase }}</h1>
        <p class="lead" >
</div>
```

Here is a great link about the difference between cloak and bind.  [Differences between ng-bind and ng-cloak in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580159/differences-between-ng-bind-and-ng-cloak-in-angularjs)

In summary, directly from that link:

[ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and
>   to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

[ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) , this will show only value after parsing.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <h1 ng-bind="application_name | uppercase"></h1>
     <p class="lead" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)** directive.

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 ng-cloak>{{application_name | uppercase }}</h1>
    <p class="lead" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) when you can => When you dont need a two-way binding but a one-way only.

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

You can also use [`ng-cloack`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.