# How to set inner html through a html tag with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In my html I use a layout like this:

```
<h2>{{translation.settings}}</h2>
```

As you might guess, I am using a multi language setup.

Now, for some reason I am required to bind the angularjs controllers later than normal and so for a brief moment `{{translation.settings}}` is rendered on my page.

Obviously this is not preferable.

I have been working with knockout for a while and one way to handle such a inconvenience is to set the element's value through a html tag, e.g.:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: translation.settings"></h2>
```

Is there a way in angularjs to set the inner element's text-value through a html-tag?

Or, since this is a possible XY problem, can I suppress the rendering of `{{translation.settings}}` in the `<h2>` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent to show the template before it get a value use ng-cloack directive. You can use documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Great, this seems to hide the values indeed.

Comment: @Stefan but rather you could also use `ng-bind` there instead of using `{{}}` interpolation directive

Comment: @PankajParkar: I'll have a look at that as well. I have to say, I am fairly new to angular, so can you explain why this is preferable?

Comment: @PankajParkar: ah, as I understand it `ng-bind` is the knockout's equivalent as I mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular

Comment: @PankajParkar: thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know.