# when should I write code with `{{}}` and without `{{}}` in html of angular js project

Tags: angularjs

May be This is a simple question but it is challenging for me.
In angularJS when i write {{}} in html code so i write code like this like 
if i talk about dynamic id, we write like code this

```
<div ng-repeat = 'item in itmes track by $index'>
   <div id = "div-{{$index}}">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

If i use any model without {{}} i write this example

```
<input id = 'name' ng-model = "item.name"/>
```

whenever i am coding in angular js, i write code without {{}} then if it is not work then i try code with {{}} and vise versa. and randomly 1 will correct
**Question is when i write code with `{{}}` and without `{{}}` in html code ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After the OP explained what exactly was the problem.

So, the question here is very simple: when do we use `{{}}` and when we don't in the context of `ng-model`.

When you do a `<input type=... ng-model="someModel>`, what you're essentially telling Angular is: "Here is an input element; attach $scope's `someModel` variable to the value of this input element.

Now, you can use this in your JavaScript controller like so: `$scope.someModel`, but what about HTML? We have a templating language in Angular, and when you give it some variable (say `someModel`), it'll search its `$scope` for it, and then put in the value there. If it is unable to, it'll throw a nasty error.

In essence, `{{}}` GETS the value, without that, you generally set the variable to gold the value of something.

---

Very simply put, AngularJS thinks that the content within the brace is an expression, which must be resolved. Once it is, Angular puts the value of the resolved expression there. In the most basic of the terms, you just tell it: "Here is some expression; put the evaluated value instead."

In ES6, we call it `template strings`.

So, you'll use it for expressions which mutate after every iteration. Say, a loop or something. Places where you know what the answer is, or you have static content, you won't use it.

Say you have the following bit of code:

```
...
...
$scope.figureOne = 10;
```

in your `controller.js` and the following in its view file:

```
<div>My age is {{ figureOne }}</div>
```

Angular gets the value from the `$scope`, and puts it there; so, the rendered form will be: `My age is 10`. However, if you had the following

```
<div>My age is figureOne</div>
```

This time, Angular knows that there is nothing to evaluate or resolve, so, it'll just render it as it is: `My age is figureOne`.

I hope I made it clear! :)

Comment: as i see your updated anser may be you dont understand my question. my english is poor, my question is when i write {{}} in attributes value like $index i gave exam. i am not ask for particular $index.

Comment: You mean: `{{$index}}` vs `$index`?

Comment: no, this is just example we use inside ng-repeat we assign `id = '{{$index}}'` in html

Comment: question is how i decide in attribute value its come with `{{}}` and without `{{}}`

Comment: Ohh!! That's exactly what I have explained.

Comment: @VipinJain I think the rule is you don't use `{{}}`in ng-* attributes. You do use them in regular attributes

Comment: @weirdpanda thank you for giving your precious time. but till now i have not to understand it, may be you did not understand my question

Comment: Hey Vipin, let's move this discussion to the chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100639/room-for-weirdpanda-and-vipin-jain

Answer (score 1):

Angular directives have different types of parameters. Some parameters (@) expect string values and some expect javascript expressions (=) (with variables bound to $scope).

There's no obvious way to know which parameter expects what type of value (aside from looking at documentation).

- If a variable expects static string value and you have an angular expression

  - then you'll need to evaluate it by wrapping in {{}}
- If there variable expects an expression and you have an expression

  - simply type that in.

Answer (score 0):

It's the best to avoid using `{{}}` where possible, your dynamic ID will fail when Angular hasn't interpolated the expression yet, use `ng-attr-id="div-{{$index}}` for that. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings

Another example, if you have a slow connection and Angular isn't loaded yet users will see the `{{}}`, you can avoid this by using `ng-bind=""`.

See this thread for more info: [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

**{{something}}** - used for one way binding(Static).

`<input type="text" value="{{something}}">`

Now if you change its value in HTML ,you can not get it by **$scope.something** in js.

but If you use **ng-model="something"**,you can get its value in JS.
This happens because **ng-model** is two way binding.

`<input type="text" ng-model="something">`

Mostly We use **ng-model** for forms and **{{}}** to display static information like User details or else.