# Does a ng-view routed template reflect the changes made as a result of a ajax request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table in this template which is being updated on ajax requests. Initially this table is empty. And when I click on the button triggering the request, the data flow is going fine but it is not reflected on the table. The table is not getting displayed at all.

Also I have a loader which displays on triggering the ajax requests. Even that is not working when I put these parts of my html inside a `ng-view` template. Is `ng-view` not supposed to be used like this? If yes, are there any other alternatives in AngularJS to solve this templating problem?

**index.html**:
Contains a `ng-view` div which is being substituted by `something.html`

**core.js**:
I have a get request getting the data into my "tables" variable by clicking on some button in the `index.html`. I have checked (using `console.log`) that the data is coming right and getting stored, the problem is that this change in the data is not getting reflected in the website.

**something.html**:
Contains the code displaying the table using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I can post some code snippets if needed

Comment: Yes. paste formatted code. Also you can try https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hey I got the change successfully reflected in something.html as long as I am generating the get request by clicking on a button belonging to something.html. But if a button belonging to index.html is used to generate a get request then the changes are not getting reflected in the something.html (which is a partial).

Answer (score 0):

I think we cannot help without code (here or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) but here is what I want to say:

1. I think it's not about `ng-view`;
2. Yes, there is at least one good alternative to replace `ng-view` - it's [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (it's provide `ui-view`). Ui-router is much more powerful, but more complicated. For you purpose, ui-router have a `resolve` section, where you should put all request that should be done before page load;
3. Also, if you need sorting, filtering and more rich function in your ajax-bsed tables, it's will be  a good choice to use [ngTables](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) library.
4. Perhaps the problem is that you didn't provide your data to html.
   I mead when you get data from server into `data` variable, you should provide it to the html via scope: `$scope.data = data;`

After that you will be able to use it in html like `<div ng-bind="data"></div>`

5. How do you make your AJAX calls? Do you use `$http` or `$resource` services? If no (if you use it with jquery for example), you should use `$scope.apply()` after this.

So, in this case you should call `$scope.apply()` each time when you update data with non-angular tools;

P.S. You may ask why not `<div>{{data}}</div>`. You know, it's perhaps the same, but angular developers suggest to use `ng-bind` instead of `{{var}}` always when it's possible (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)).

Comment: Is it possible to send ajax requests and update the view of the template given that it is already rendered in the ng-view portion?

Comment: That exactly how it should work, so yes. But still don't know where your problem is. So, in common case, angular will update each variable in `$scope`.

Comment: I use $http service for sending the get request.