# ng-bind directive for Html display elements

Tags: angularjs

As my understandings, for Html display (read only) elements, ng-model is not supposed to use. Instead {{scope-variable}} syntax is used.  I have a question for the usage of ng-bind. Is there any behavior difference for the 2 following div elements?

The following div element has ng-bind directive as one of its attributes:

```
 <div class="col-md-7" style="border: 1px solid #8fbc8f; min-height: 200px;" ng-binding="myContents">
     {{myContents}}
 </div>
```

And the following div element does not have ng-bind directive as one of its attributes:

```
 <div class="col-md-7" style="border: 1px solid #8fbc8f; min-height: 200px;">
     {{myContents}}
 </div>
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular#answer-23382400).

Comment: There is no sense of using {{}} with ng-bind. One or another.