# Can't display data from $http get with angular, django

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

i have an application developed with Django in backend, where was created an API to can read information in the frontend with angular.

I'm calling with $http a list of persons in database, in the function i get the data, and display with console.log and is correct, but when i call that information in the template with ng-repeat, the content divs are created but the information inside not display, stays blank.

I will appreciate any sugestion to solve this.

**// custom-angular.js**

```
var app = angular.module('SesamoApp', []);

var URL = '/api/projects/torres-de-monterrey/segmentation/';

app.controller('cardsCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.cards = [
    {email: 'email@correo.com', segment: 'low'}
];

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: URL
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    /*console.log(response.data);*/
    $scope.data = response.data;

    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key){
        console.log(key + ': ' + value.email + ' -- ' + value.segment);
        $scope.cards.push({email: value.email, segment: value.segment});
    });

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });

console.log($scope.cards);

}]);
```

---

**// list.html**

```
{% extends "base_app.html" %}
{% block main-container %}
    <h1>Actividades de hoy</h1>
    {% if activities %}
        {% for activity in activities %}
            {{activity.activity_type}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>No tienes actividades programadas para hoy</p>
        <hr />

        <div class="segmentBlocks">
            <div ng-app="SesamoApp">
                <div class="cards" ng-controller="cardsCtrl">
                    <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:'segment'">
                        <p class="email">{{ card.email }}</p>
                        <p class="segment">{{ card.segment }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {{ data }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

Screenshot with the result after execution (No info)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHrNi.png)

Comment: `console.log(key + ': ' + value.email + ' -- ' + value.segment);` does it reproduces well in your console?

Comment: Yes, show all the information correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your angular bracket **{{ }}** to **{$ $}** by adding this line in your app.js.

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$interpolateProvider',     function($httpProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
}])
```

then do this

```
<div class="segmentBlocks">
        <div ng-app="SesamoApp">
            <div class="cards" ng-controller="cardsCtrl">
                <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in cards | orderBy:'segment'">
                    <p class="email">{$ card.email $}</p>
                    <p class="segment">{$ card.segment $}</p>
                </div>
                {$ data $}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It might be pride of authorship, but I feel this is an inferior solution to my answer. It's an unnecessary fix that adds unnecessary complexity and `ngBind` is also generally preferable over `{{}}` anyway. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular

Comment: @miyamoto I never used ng-bind before. Gonna take a look at this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the Django templating is parsing your brackets in the ngRepeat block as part of the Django template rather than leaving it for the Angular controller. Instead of using `{{}}` here, why not use [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) and add `ng-bind="card.email"` and `ng-bind="card.segment"` attributes to your `p` tags?

Otherwise, escape the Django templating with a [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tag around the relevant angular blocks.