# Display AngularJS array to a 'human' readable string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, string-formatting

I have outputted a variable that is an array within my view and while it is displaying the values as following :-

```
Inbound bound posts will contain ["phone", "car"]
```

How do I change this to display this in a human format eg. (as below)

Inbound bound posts will contain phone, car

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you simply want to list the array you can use `join`:

```
arr = ["phone", "car"];
arr.join(", ");
```

would output: "phone, car".

Answer (score 2):

To make array displayed as series of texts

```
Inbound bound posts will contain {{ ["phone", "car"].join(', ') }}
```

Comment: It is better to keep the logic out of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method on your controller to handle the array->string:

```
let arrayToWrite = ['phone', 'car'];
aToS() {
  return arrayToWrite.join(' ');
}
```

Then your view:

```
Inbound bound posts will contain {{ vm.aToS() }}
```

(assuming 'vm' is your controller, as per standard convention)

You could input the array to the method too, if you need, rather than defining the array outside the method.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives. You could also do this:

```
    <div>
      Inbound bound posts will contain
      <span ng-repeat="obj in objects">{{obj}} </span>
    </div>
```

and in your controller hold the list on scope:

```
$scope.objects = ["car", "phone"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter:

```
myApp.filter('join', function () {
    return function join(array, separator, prop) {
        if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
            return array; // if not array return original - can also throw error
        }

        return (!!prop ? array.map(function (item) {
            return item[prop];
        }) : array).join(separator);
    };
});
```

And in your HTML, simply write this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Inbound bound posts will contain {{things | join: ', ' }}
</div>
```

A working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12345/

Comment: Question have Array in view.So Is code have higher priority than data??

Comment: Best practice is to keep the logic out of the view. You should define your array in your controller for example. This is also needed for unit testing, code readability, reusability etc etc.

Comment: Then why are you using expressions inside your view?

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of Angular? ;-)

Comment: using expressions inside the code is also not a best practice,lets use ng-bind and change the code.

Comment: Basically the double-curly syntax is more naturally readable and requires less typing.

ng-bind still has an issue with displaying arrays from a factory in a view. But indeed, ng-bind would be better if you do not want to have a chance that the user would see the {{expression}} before all data is loaded.

Comment: Just go through this, if you are new to angularjs
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular/23382400#23382400

Comment: I'm not entirely new to Angular, but thanks for the info. I just want to point out that since early 2015 curly interpolation is handled just like a directive (see addTextInterpolateDirective() in ng/compile.js).