# data-ng-bind does not work with <option> element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind

I've just started learning angular and got stuck on this problem. I read on [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular) that `{{}}` and `ng-bind` will give you the same outcome. However, it is not the case for the codes below:

JS

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module("myApp", [])
        .controller("selectCtrl2", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/testService/name.php"
            })
            .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.content;},
             function (response) {$scope.names = response.statusText;});
        });
})();
```

HTML

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="selectCtrl2">
        <select>
            <option data-ng-repeat="x in names">
                <span data-ng-bind="x"></span>
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

ng-repeat actually created 3 option tags, but their innerHTML were spaces only.
For some weird reasons, if I used {{x}}, their innerHTML would be filled with the text in an array I prepared [a, b, c]. I wonder what could be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is illegal HTML to have a `<span>` element inside `<option>` elements.The only permitted content is text.

Move the [ng-bind directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)  to the [`<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) and it will work.

## The Demo

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <div ng-init="names=['fred','sam','jane']">
     
        <select>
            <!-- ILLEGAL HTML
            <option data-ng-repeat="x in names">
                <span data-ng-bind="x"></span>
            </option>
            -->

            <!-- PERMITTED -->
            <option data-ng-repeat="x in names" ng-bind="x">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </body>
```

With the [ng-bind directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) as part of the [`<option>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), the directive will insert only the text result of the [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) which is legal HTML and permitted content.

From the MDN Docs:

> The HTML `<option>` element is used to define an item contained in a `<select>`, an `<optgroup>`, or a `<datalist>` element. As such,  can represent menu items in popups and other lists of items in an HTML document.
>
> ```
> Content categories   None.
> Permitted content    Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).
> ```
>
> [— MDN HTML Element Reference - `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Also see,

- [AngularJS `select` Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

Answer (score 0):

From [the answer by Konstantin Krass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/1575353):

> This `ng-bind` is a *directive* and will place a watcher on the passed
>   variable. So the `ng-bind` will only apply, when the **passed value does
>   actually change**.
>
> The brackets on the other hand will be **dirty checked** and refreshed in
>   **every** `$digest`, even if it's **not necessary**. <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/1575353)</sup>

#### UPDATE:

the main reason is solved in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44489733/1575353) by [georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5535245/georgeawg)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/1575353</sub>

Comment: @SamOnela It is written at the end of the quote
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular

Comment: mmm i think because it make sense