# Angular: ng-model directive not working with `<span>` element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am currently working on a web application that uses bootstrap and angular.js, and I was running into some difficulty setting the default value of a `span` embedded within the HTML code of one of the pages.

Previously, I was able to use `ng-model` to set and modify the values of an HTML element within the HTML code from the angular controller found in a separate file.  This is what the controller looks like:

```
angular.module('mediaPlaylistApp', [])
    .controller('mediaPlaylistCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedProperties', .....,
        function($scope, sharedProperties, .....,){
        //many lines of code in here
}]);
```

Within this, I am able to set attributes of the `$scope` variable that can then be used by elements on the HTML page.  For example, I can set a checkbox to be checked with the following JS line in the above controller:

```
$scope.areAllSelected = true;
```

When it is used in conjunction with the following HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="areAllSelected">
```

This works as expected.  **However**, my issue arises when I try to replicate this technique for a different `span` element.

When I insert this JS line into the angular controller:

```
$scope.playlistName = 'Enter Playlist Name Here';
```

In conjunction with this HTML code:

```
<span ng-model="playlistName">
</span>
```

It does not work as expected, as the `span` remains blank and not displaying the string `'Enter Playlist Name Here'`.  What could be causing this behavior?  Does `ng-model` not work for elements other than `input`, or is it a simple mistake I've made or a completely unrelated issue?  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the docs:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

> "The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive."

Yes, you can't use `ng-model` with span. Instead you can use `ng-bind`.

```
<span ng-bind="playlistName"></span>
```

Alternative is that you can wrap the value defined on scope with interpolation operator `{{}}`

```
  <span>{{playlistName}}</span>
```

[Why ng-bind is better than {{}} ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Comment: `ng-bind` operates the same as the {{ }} as far as one/two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. `ng-models` sets the value of the element while `span` has no inherent value.  You have to display it like this:

```
<span>
{{playlistName}}
</span>
```