# How to ng-bind on html data attributes and placeholders?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

As we know it is good to use `ng-bind` instead of `{{expression}}` considering performance which is clearly mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Similar to this, just want to understand how can we bind `class` attributes or `data` attributes or any other properties which is not related to html display elements?

Ex: We can bind to `span` element like: `<span ng-bind="vm.bindText"></span>`

Where as what if we want to bind for `class` without any conditions or using `ng-class` and also `directives`

Now it looks like this:
`<span class="{{vm.bindText}}"></span>`

And this implementation works for class: `<span ng-class="vm.bindText"></span>`

But how to do it on custom data attributes like: `<input data-id="vm.bindOldId" placeholder="vm.bindText">` instead of `<input data-id="{{vm.bindOldId}}" placeholder="{{vm.bindText}}">`

Just curious to know about this and does it really makes sense of doing it as well?

Let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use `ng-class`?

```
ng-class="vm.bindText"
```

You can add data attributes like so to:

```
ng-attr-data-YOUR_ATTRIBUTE="YOUR VALUE"
```

Comment: Yup, ng-class works. For `data-id`, tried using `ng-attr-data-id="vm.bindText"`, but its just displayed as: `data-id="vm.bindText"` instead of its value

Comment: It will work for:  ng-attr-data-id="{{vm.bindText}}", without expression is there a way or what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to add the value of what `vm.bindText` is, then you will need to evaluate it using braces: `ng-attr-data-id="{{vm.bindText}}`. Without braces you are setting it to the string `vm.bindText`

Comment: That expression evaluation relies on continues scope life cycle update and impacts in performance rite? How about placeholders ?