# Totally prevent displaying of curly braces in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want curly braces to be never displayed to user.
I know about ng-cloak, but it seems not hiding them during link function...

Here is modified [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FkUMQyKkoGARRSIYvszo?p=preview) from angular docs.

I added ng-cloak to my-pane.html:

```
<div class="tab-pane ng-cloak ng-cloak" ng-cloak ng-show="selected">
```

and css for ng-cloak to index.html:

```
 [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, 
 .x-ng-cloak {
   display: none !important;
 }
```

And a breakpoint to link function of 'myPane' directive:

```
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
    tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
    debugger;
  },
```

Open dev tools and rerun the plunk. When execution stops on breakpoint, curl braces are visible to user.

Is it possible to fix it somehow - angular way would be nice :)

Comment: If you remove the breakpoint, does it display the curly braces?

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-cloak` on the `body` ?

Comment: @rrd without breakpoint it instantly process the template, it is done very fast , breakpoint is needed to see what is displayed to user on during link function

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu I tried, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind instead of {{ }} as it's designed to stop the very issue you're running into. Please see this SO answer: [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular)

Comment: I want **all** my content to be hidden until it is not processed, 'ng-bind' hides only a part of it.