# AngularJS template binding to object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch, angularjs-bindings

As we all know AngularJS uses the simplest form of `$watch` when we bind to variable in template like this `{{ $ctrl.obj }}`.
It should compare value of `$ctrl.obj` by reference, but if I mutate `$ctrl.obj` the change is reflected in view. The reference doesn't changed, so why?

Comment: See my latest answer. Your last comment made me realize my previous answer was wrong. BTW, according to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngBind.js#L62), the `ngBind` directive do not use the third parameter: the relevant part is: `scope.$watch(attr.ngBind, function ngBindWatchAction(value) {
          element.textContent = stringify(value);
        });`

Answer (score 0):

When we use brackets (`{{}}`) angular does not use any `watch` (ers) for detecting changes on the expression placed inside them. Instead this expression is **dirty checked** and refreshed in every `$digest` cycle, even if it is not necessary.

See this post: [AngularJS : Why ng-bind is better than {{}} in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular/23382400#23382400)